# Importing Data from .txt file to SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

I have a tab separated .txt (Very Small file with just 10 to 15 datasets) and this file is having some columns as **PrdName, PrdSize, PrdWeight, PrdCode** and so on.

Now I want to import the two columns which are **PrdSize** and **PrdCode** and import it in the columns of my Database table.
I have created the columns but how do I create import clause and transfer data from .txt file to SQL Server? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post: [Import/Export data with SQL Server 2005 Express](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/546f4407-0aa4-4b04-96f3-e6f0ba39a9d1/), there are multiple options that you can use.

Comment: I see, I'll download the specified Toolkit then...Thanks

Comment: In SQL Server 2000, you can right click on the database in Object Explorer and choose Tasks - Import Data ...

Comment: All right, well then I'll do this way. So how about Import Clause, do I need to create import clause after the import data? Is it possible in this Management studio?

Comment: Jasmine, you can save it as a package at the end of the wizard and then execute this package as a job or from you procedure. But what is your ultimate goal? Is it one time load or long term automated  solution?

Comment: The goal is to create Import SSIS package and create .dtsx file at the end. I tried SQL Server 2000 and somehow reached to the point where it created the complete database from the tab separated file but my goal is to insert those columns data in an already built database and only particular columns.

Comment: Jasmine, when choosing destination in the wizard, you should be able to see your existing db in the list. Later steps will allow you to only populate 2 columns.

Comment: Jasmine, you can't create SSIS package in SQL Server 2000, but you can create DTS package (similar, but older technology). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143706%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx#express for SSIS/DTS Compatibility in SQL Server 2005 Express.

Comment: Thank you nikadim. I think best would be to setup the trial version of full sql server and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the express edition you'll need to either use [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or write a program with something else.

Comment: Would it be possible to perform this task on SQL Server 2000? I've that also in a different computer. It's basically a very small .txt file.

Comment: @Jasmine Appelblad SQL 2000 DTS has a FileSource, but I don't know if the destination can be SQL 2005 express. You should try it and see

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large amount of data, or need to automate the process, definitely look into BCP as mentioned already. However, I often use excel to load one-time data sources (a few hundred to a few thousand) rows of data from odd sources into SQL Server by doing the following:

Get the data into excel (that's usually easy), assuming you get column A with 'Prdsize' and column B with PrdCode, in column C put the formula:

```
="INSERT INTO MYTABLE(PRDSIZE, PRODCODE) VALUES (" & a1 & "," & B1 & ")"
```

(in other words create syntactically correct SQL using an Excel formula - you may need to add quotes around string values etc)

and then paste that formula all the way down the column C. Then copy/paste the resultant sql insert statements into SQL Management Studio, or any other tool that can execute SQL and execute it.

Defintely a 'manual' effort, but for one-time data loads it words great.

PS: You'll need to verify the XL formula and the resultant sql syntax - my example is close, but I didn't test it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you EJB. The .txt file is very small but I need to go from the procedure only. Need to create an Import clause only.